# Beta-Status der German Language Seite

Tags: support, statistics

[image]
[<sub>Bildquelle</sub>](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity)

Wie ein Stern am Ende seines Lebens zum Weißen Zwerg wird und erkaltet, so endet eine letztlich scheiternde Beta-Seite als Dump, wie man dem Bild entnehmen kann.

Kennt jemand (analog den oben angezeigten Daten) die Ist- und Soll-Werte für die German-Seite?

Comment: Am Rande: Die einzigen mir bekannten Fälle von Seiten, die nach einer längeren Zeit als Public Beta geschlossen wurden (wie Dein Beispiel), hatten Probleme anderer Natur, z. B. dass die Seiten verwahrlosten und sich niemand fand, der die Seite moderieren wollten.

Comment: ([Quelle](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/598/2018/2/16))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Soll-Werte sind für alle Betas gleich, stehen also auch schon oben im Bild. Für German Language sagt die Seite [Area 51 » Culture » German Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language) zur Zeit:

> **2505 days in beta**
>
> **4.6 questions per day**    Needs Work  – 10 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some
> work. A healthy site generates lots of good content to make sure users
> keep coming back.
>
> **100%  answered**     Excellent – 90% answered is a healthy beta, 80% answered needs some work. In the beta it's especially important that
> when new visitors ask questions they usually get a good answer.
>
> **1,107 avid users / 20,607 total users**    Excellent – Every site needs a solid group of core users to assist in moderating the site. We
> recommend:    150 users with 200+ rep (currently 1,107 users with 200+
> rep)   10 users with 2,000+ rep (currently 109 users with 2,000+ rep)
> 5 users with 3,000+ rep (currently 72 users with 3,000+ rep)
>
> **2.3 answer ratio**    Okay – 2.5 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question needs some work. On a healthy site, questions
> receive multiple answers and the best answer is voted to the top.
>
> **10,746  visits/day**     Excellent – 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work. A great site benefits people
> outside the community. Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come
> from search engines.

Wie es scheint sind solche Statistiken nicht besonders aussagekräftig, wie an der zahlenmäßig passabel aussehenden Seite [Startup Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) zu illustrieren wäre.

Einen mit diesen groben Zahlen nicht erfassten Bereich stellt die Community Moderation dar. Zu lang werdende Review queues, SPAM, nicht geschlossene Fragen, die geschlossen werden müssten, Moderatorensterben und ähnliche Phänomene sollten ebenfalls beachtet werden.

Eine offiziellere Sicht von oben auf

> [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)
> The TL;DR:
>
> - When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.
> - **If a public beta site does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed.**

Auch wenn die Gefahr, als site zu erkalten, für German Language wohl nicht akut zu sein scheint und die Richtwerte nicht unbedingt als in Stein gemeißelt anzusehen sind: die Richtwerte gelten wohl zuerst für das positive Verlassen des beta-Status: Graduation to full site!

Wie Takkat kommentierte: dafür scheint es auch noch etwas mehr Aktivität und Beteiligung hier auf der Metaseite zu brauchen?

Comment: Wobei dem hinzugefügt werden muss, dass die Soll-Werte außer 10 Fragen pro Tag als überholt angesehen werden ([von SE selbst](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/255554)).

Comment: Und mein unbestätigter Eindruck ist auch, dass eine funktionierende Community Moderation ein wesentlich wichtigerer Faktor ist als all die Statistiken oben. @Wrzlprmft: any links for that? (Please edit the above, if.)

Comment: @LangLangC: und zu einer aktiven Community gehört sicher auch eine **wesentlich** bessere Meta-Beteiligung.